# Returning a different mime-type in Python Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I have a simple Python Bottle application that is mainly returning HTML pages.

But one option needs to return plain text (mime-type "text/text")

```
@get('/raw/<id>')
def get_raw(id) :
    return get_data(id)
```

How do I tell the function to return this type?

Comment: Did you try setting `response.content_type = 'text/text'`?

Comment: Yep. That's it.

Comment: I was trying set_contenttype("text/text") but that wasn't working

Comment: Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd recommend reading through the docs: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content):

> #### Changing the Default Encoding
>
> Bottle uses the *charset* parameter of the `Content-Type` header to
>   decide how to encode unicode strings. This header defaults to
>   `text/html; charset=UTF8` and can be changed using the
>   `Response.content_type` attribute or by setting the Response.charset
>   attribute directly. (The [`Response`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Response) object is described in the
>   section [The Response Object](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#tutorial-response).)
>
> ```
> from bottle import response
> @route('/iso')
> def get_iso():
>     response.charset = 'ISO-8859-15'
>     return u'This will be sent with ISO-8859-15 encoding.'
>
> @route('/latin9')
> def get_latin():
>     response.content_type = 'text/html; charset=latin9'
>     return u'ISO-8859-15 is also known as latin9.'
> ```

In your case, therefore, you just want:

```
response.content_type = 'text/text; charset=UTF8'
```